# javafx NullPointerException when rendering big image

Tags: java, image, javafx

I'm trying to render a .png Image using the `GraphicsContext.drawImage(...)` method under JavaFX 8. My code works perfectly fine for an image of size ~1000px x 2000px. 
But unfortunately I need to render an image of size 7000px x 14000px. Loading this image works fine as well, but when calling the `drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight())` method I get the following error output:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.prism.impl.BaseGraphics.drawTexture(BaseGraphics.java:389)
at com.sun.prism.impl.ps.BaseShaderGraphics.drawTexture(BaseShaderGraphics.java:139)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGCanvas.handleRenderOp(NGCanvas.java:1228)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGCanvas.renderStream(NGCanvas.java:997)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGCanvas.renderContent(NGCanvas.java:578)
... more rendering stuff here
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2043)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1951)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.doPaint(ViewPainter.java:469)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.paintImpl(ViewPainter.java:317)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run(PresentingPainter.java:89)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:58)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:129)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It doesn't make a difference if I try to resize the image while drawing to the canvas or if I try to render the whole image.

My guess is that the image size is simply too big to render, but I could'nt find any source to validate this and neither could I find anything to solve my problem.

I also made an analysis of the Java heap (with Eclipse Memory Analyzer) which showed an image size of approximately 376 MB.

So basically my question are:
1. Why is my program crashing? Is it because the image is too big?
2. If my image is too big, how can I increase the available space for Java? My machine has 8GB RAM and the graphics card has 1GB RAM, so an image of <400MB should not really be a problem.

Comment: Did you try increasing the heap size ?

Comment: Yes, I tried it using 4GB. And I'm not getting a `OutOfMemoryError`, but a `NullPointerException` which also means that my program is still running after the Exception is thrown. It just can't render the canvas any longer.

Comment: Yes, I know that ! Its quite strange that you are getting a `NullPointerException` for a large image !

Comment: Might be related to a some bug tracker issues [RT-36386](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-36386), [RT-36540](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-36540), [RT-32258](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-32258).  I guess you could report it at https://javafx-jira.kenai.com if none of the linked issues seem like duplicates (or their resolutions don't seem satisfactory).  7Kx14K is a really big image...

Comment: Related [Oracle forum discussion](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3549359) may be useful.  My guess is that either 8Kx8K or 4Kx4K images will work on your hardware/software combo, but larger images may not.

Answer (score 8):

As somebody pointed in comments - only up tp 4k/8k textures will work for you. This is because JavaFX probably uses GPU to render images. Texture size limit is probably the limit of yout GPU or GPU drivers that can't handle bigger textures. It can't create so big texture so it returns null (and that explains the NullPointerException).

The only way to fix it is to avoid using so big textures or get better hardware to support bigger textures. Using software rendering (which may be really slow) may fix it by running java with the following parameters:

```
-Dprism.order=j2d
```

or

```
-Dprism.order=sw
```

But I'm not sure it's what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

I could solve it with the 2 VM-Arguments:

```
-Dprism.order=sw
-Xmx1024m
```

I needed both of them.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it for me with VM-Arguments:

`-Dprism.poolstats=true 
 -Dprism.maxvram=500m 
 -Dprism.order=sw 
 -Djavafx.animation.fullspeed=true`