# JavaFX WebKit crash after building some big strings

Tags: javafx, memory-leaks, crash, webkit, webengine

This code produces a crash in my machine after clicking [Do it!] twice:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class TestJFX extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(new Browser(), 800, 600, Color.web("#666970")));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}

class Browser extends Region {

    public Browser() {
        WebView browser = new WebView();
        WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();

        webEngine.loadContent("<html>"
                + "<body><input type='button' onclick='getHugeString()' value='Do it!'>"
                    + "<script type='text/javascript'>"
                        + "function getHugeString() {"
                            + "text = '';"
                            + "for (var i=0;i<1024*1024*20;i++) {"
                                + "text += 'a';"
                            + "}"
                        + "}"
                    + "</script>"
                + "</body>"
            + "</html>", "text/html");

        getChildren().add(browser);
    }

}
```

Crash report:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x62def78b, pid=13008, tid=4864
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_80-b15) (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.80-b11 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [jfxwebkit.dll+0x74f78b]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00412400):  JavaThread "JavaFX Application Thread" [_thread_in_native, id=4864, stack(0x05510000,0x05560000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, writing address 0xbbadbeef

Registers:
EAX=0x00000000, EBX=0x0001f000, ECX=0x00000000, EDX=0x05560000
ESP=0x0555dec0, EBP=0x00010000, ESI=0x00000000, EDI=0x00000000
EIP=0x62def78b, EFLAGS=0x00210246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0555dec0)
0x0555dec0:   0000ffff 62e30f3f 0001f000 ffffffff
0x0555ded0:   00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000
0x0555dee0:   04daced4 07290080 04dacea0 62e305ed
0x0555def0:   0555df08 00010000 00010000 ffffffff
0x0555df00:   00000001 00000000 04dad24c 07290080
0x0555df10:   00000000 04dacea0 04daced4 07290080
0x0555df20:   62dc5963 04dacea0 00000020 00000001
0x0555df30:   04daced4 00000000 00000000 00000001 

Instructions: (pc=0x62def78b)
0x62def76b:   68 00 20 00 00 50 6a 00 ff 15 48 60 f7 62 8b f0
0x62def77b:   85 f6 75 14 e8 1c b7 fc ff e8 97 b7 fc ff 33 c9
0x62def78b:   89 35 ef be ad bb ff d1 8b c6 5e c3 cc cc cc cc
0x62def79b:   cc cc cc cc cc 80 7c 24 10 00 74 11 0f b6 44 24 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
EBX=0x0001f000 is an unknown value
ECX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
EDX=0x05560000 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00412400
ESP=0x0555dec0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00412400
EBP=0x00010000 is an unknown value
ESI=0x00000000 is an unknown value
EDI=0x00000000 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x05510000,0x05560000],  sp=0x0555dec0,  free space=311k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [jfxwebkit.dll+0x74f78b]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.sun.webpane.platform.WebPage.twkProcessMouseEvent(JIIIIIIIZZZZZF)Z+0
j  com.sun.webpane.platform.WebPage.dispatchMouseEvent(Lcom/sun/webpane/platform/event/WCMouseEvent;)Z+134
j  javafx.scene.web.WebView.processMouseEvent(Ljavafx/scene/input/MouseEvent;)V+111
j  javafx.scene.web.WebView.access$2600(Ljavafx/scene/web/WebView;Ljavafx/scene/input/MouseEvent;)V+2
j  javafx.scene.web.WebView$14.handle(Ljavafx/scene/input/MouseEvent;)V+5
j  javafx.scene.web.WebView$14.handle(Ljavafx/event/Event;)V+5
j  com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Ljavafx/event/Event;)V+42
j  com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Ljavafx/event/EventType;Ljavafx/event/Event;)Ljavafx/event/Event;+29
j  com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Ljavafx/event/Event;)Ljavafx/event/Event;+8
j  com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Ljavafx/event/Event;)Ljavafx/event/Event;+11
j  com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Ljavafx/event/Event;Ljavafx/event/EventDispatchChain;)Ljavafx/event/Event;+29
j  com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Ljavafx/event/Event;)Ljavafx/event/Event;+69
j  com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Ljavafx/event/Event;Ljavafx/event/EventDispatchChain;)Ljavafx/event/Event;+17
j  com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Ljavafx/event/Event;)Ljavafx/event/Event;+69
j  com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Ljavafx/event/EventDispatchChain;Ljavafx/event/EventTarget;Ljavafx/event/Event;)Ljavafx/event/Event;+10
j  com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Ljavafx/event/EventTarget;Ljavafx/event/Event;)Ljavafx/event/Event;+46
j  javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Ljavafx/event/EventTarget;Ljavafx/event/Event;)V+30
j  javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Ljavafx/scene/input/MouseEvent;Z)V+405
j  javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Ljavafx/scene/input/MouseEvent;)V+3
j  javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Ljavafx/scene/Scene$MouseHandler;Ljavafx/scene/input/MouseEvent;)V+2
j  javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Ljavafx/scene/input/MouseEvent;)V+16
j  javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Ljava/lang/Object;)V+11
j  com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run()Ljava/lang/Void;+329
j  com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
J 175  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object; (0 bytes) @ 0x028aed47 [0x028aece0+0x67]
j  com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Lcom/sun/glass/ui/View;JIIIIIIIIZZ)V+117
j  com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(JIIIIIIIIZZ)V+38
j  com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(IIIIIIIZZ)V+184
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop([Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/sun/glass/ui/Launchable;)V+0
j  com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(Lcom/sun/glass/ui/win/WinApplication;[Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/sun/glass/ui/Launchable;)V+3
j  com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run()V+32
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00413800 JavaThread "Prism Font Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6352, stack(0x07f40000,0x07f90000)]
  0x00413000 JavaThread "Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7404, stack(0x07170000,0x071c0000)]
  0x00412800 JavaThread "Thread-3" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=9536, stack(0x07020000,0x07070000)]
=>0x00412400 JavaThread "JavaFX Application Thread" [_thread_in_native, id=4864, stack(0x05510000,0x05560000)]
  0x00411c00 JavaThread "Thread-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3924, stack(0x05750000,0x057a0000)]
  0x00411800 JavaThread "Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1400, stack(0x05570000,0x055c0000)]
  0x00411000 JavaThread "QuantumRenderer-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5780, stack(0x05140000,0x05190000)]
  0x00410c00 JavaThread "JavaFX-Launcher" [_thread_blocked, id=2488, stack(0x04c50000,0x04ca0000)]
  0x00410400 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13068, stack(0x047d0000,0x04820000)]
  0x0041b400 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13280, stack(0x012c0000,0x01310000)]
  0x0040fc00 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10072, stack(0x04880000,0x048d0000)]
  0x0040f800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5280, stack(0x04830000,0x04880000)]
  0x003a5800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6084, stack(0x011b0000,0x01200000)]
  0x003a0400 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12148, stack(0x00f30000,0x00f80000)]
  0x0107e800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_blocked, id=7572, stack(0x00ed0000,0x00f20000)]

Other Threads:
  0x0039ec00 VMThread [stack: 0x010b0000,0x01100000] [id=11396]
  0x0043bc00 WatcherThread [stack: 0x01230000,0x01280000] [id=6260]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 2344K [0x24400000, 0x24950000, 0x29950000)
  eden space 4416K,  41% used [0x24400000, 0x245ca300, 0x24850000)
  from space 512K, 100% used [0x248d0000, 0x24950000, 0x24950000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x24850000, 0x24850000, 0x248d0000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 1445K [0x29950000, 0x2a400000, 0x34400000)
   the space 10944K,  13% used [0x29950000, 0x29ab9418, 0x29ab9600, 0x2a400000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 4428K [0x34400000, 0x35000000, 0x38400000)
   the space 12288K,  36% used [0x34400000, 0x348531a0, 0x34853200, 0x35000000)
    ro space 10240K,  44% used [0x38400000, 0x3887d3a8, 0x3887d400, 0x38e00000)
    rw space 12288K,  52% used [0x38e00000, 0x39449a18, 0x39449c00, 0x39a00000)

Card table byte_map: [0x009a0000,0x00a50000] byte_map_base: 0x0087e000

Polling page: 0x001e0000

Code Cache  [0x027c0000, 0x028b8000, 0x047c0000)
 total_blobs=529 nmethods=200 adapters=266 free_code_cache=31787Kb largest_free_block=32550784

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 9.532 Thread 0x0041b400  195             com.sun.scenario.animation.AnimationPulse$AnimationPulseHolder::access$000 (4 bytes)
Event: 9.532 Thread 0x0041b400 nmethod 195 0x028b3c48 code [0x028b3d40, 0x028b3db0]
Event: 9.532 Thread 0x0041b400  196             com.sun.scenario.animation.AnimationPulse::getEnabled (5 bytes)
Event: 9.532 Thread 0x0041b400 nmethod 196 0x028b3e08 code [0x028b3f00, 0x028b3f80]
Event: 9.532 Thread 0x0041b400  197             java.util.WeakHashMap::clear (50 bytes)
Event: 9.532 Thread 0x0041b400 nmethod 197 0x028b3fc8 code [0x028b4100, 0x028b4578]
Event: 10.044 Thread 0x0041b400  198  s          com.sun.webpane.platform.Invoker::getInvoker (4 bytes)
Event: 10.044 Thread 0x0041b400 nmethod 198 0x028b4808 code [0x028b4900, 0x028b4ac0]
Event: 10.844 Thread 0x0041b400  199             javafx.scene.Scene::getWindow (22 bytes)
Event: 10.844 Thread 0x0041b400 nmethod 199 0x028b4b48 code [0x028b4c50, 0x028b4d4c]

GC Heap History (2 events):
Event: 0.334 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=0 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 4416K [0x24400000, 0x24950000, 0x29950000)
  eden space 4416K, 100% used [0x24400000, 0x24850000, 0x24850000)
  from space 512K,   0% used [0x24850000, 0x24850000, 0x248d0000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x248d0000, 0x248d0000, 0x24950000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 0K [0x29950000, 0x2a400000, 0x34400000)
   the space 10944K,   0% used [0x29950000, 0x29950000, 0x29950200, 0x2a400000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 3545K [0x34400000, 0x35000000, 0x38400000)
   the space 12288K,  28% used [0x34400000, 0x34776748, 0x34776800, 0x35000000)
    ro space 10240K,  44% used [0x38400000, 0x3887d3a8, 0x3887d400, 0x38e00000)
    rw space 12288K,  52% used [0x38e00000, 0x39449a18, 0x39449c00, 0x39a00000)
Event: 0.343 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 512K [0x24400000, 0x24950000, 0x29950000)
  eden space 4416K,   0% used [0x24400000, 0x24400000, 0x24850000)
  from space 512K, 100% used [0x248d0000, 0x24950000, 0x24950000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x24850000, 0x24850000, 0x248d0000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 1445K [0x29950000, 0x2a400000, 0x34400000)
   the space 10944K,  13% used [0x29950000, 0x29ab9418, 0x29ab9600, 0x2a400000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 3545K [0x34400000, 0x35000000, 0x38400000)
   the space 12288K,  28% used [0x34400000, 0x34776748, 0x34776800, 0x35000000)
    ro space 10240K,  44% used [0x38400000, 0x3887d3a8, 0x3887d400, 0x38e00000)
    rw space 12288K,  52% used [0x38e00000, 0x39449a18, 0x39449c00, 0x39a00000)
}

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 0.083 Thread 0x00410c00 Threw 0x24558228 at C:\re\jdk7u80\2329\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1319
Event: 0.092 Thread 0x00410c00 Threw 0x245c5e30 at C:\re\jdk7u80\2329\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\linkResolver.cpp:892
Event: 0.132 Thread 0x00412400 Threw 0x245ff410 at C:\re\jdk7u80\2329\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\linkResolver.cpp:892
Event: 0.132 Thread 0x00412400 Threw 0x245ff410 at C:\re\jdk7u80\2329\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1323
Event: 0.148 Thread 0x00412400 Threw 0x24654970 at C:\re\jdk7u80\2329\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1319
Event: 0.148 Thread 0x00412400 Threw 0x246590f8 at C:\re\jdk7u80\2329\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1319
Event: 0.150 Thread 0x00412400 Threw 0x246614d8 at C:\re\jdk7u80\2329\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1319
Event: 0.151 Thread 0x00412400 Threw 0x24666240 at C:\re\jdk7u80\2329\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1319
Event: 0.151 Thread 0x00412400 Threw 0x2466b9e0 at C:\re\jdk7u80\2329\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1319
Event: 0.151 Thread 0x00412400 Threw 0x246708f8 at C:\re\jdk7u80\2329\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1319

Events (10 events):
Event: 1.483 loading class 0x04e0be20
Event: 1.483 loading class 0x04e0be20 done
Event: 2.785 loading class 0x04a85ce0
Event: 2.785 loading class 0x04a85ce0 done
Event: 4.176 Executing VM operation: EnableBiasedLocking
Event: 4.177 Executing VM operation: EnableBiasedLocking done
Event: 12.477 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 12.477 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 12.477 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 12.477 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done


Dynamic libraries:
0x01390000 - 0x013bf000     D:\usr\java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\bin\javaw.exe
0x774d0000 - 0x77650000     C:\windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
0x75cc0000 - 0x75dd0000     C:\windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
0x75b90000 - 0x75bd7000     C:\windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
0x762b0000 - 0x76351000     C:\windows\syswow64\ADVAPI32.dll
0x76660000 - 0x7670c000     C:\windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll
0x74db0000 - 0x74dc9000     C:\windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll
0x763a0000 - 0x76490000     C:\windows\syswow64\RPCRT4.dll
0x74b80000 - 0x74be0000     C:\windows\syswow64\SspiCli.dll
0x74b70000 - 0x74b7c000     C:\windows\syswow64\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x76af0000 - 0x76bf0000     C:\windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
0x75b00000 - 0x75b90000     C:\windows\syswow64\GDI32.dll
0x76770000 - 0x7677a000     C:\windows\syswow64\LPK.dll
0x74c80000 - 0x74d1d000     C:\windows\syswow64\USP10.dll
0x73200000 - 0x7339e000     C:\windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.18837_none_41e855142bd5705d\COMCTL32.dll
0x76250000 - 0x762a7000     C:\windows\syswow64\SHLWAPI.dll
0x75dd0000 - 0x75e30000     C:\windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x75be0000 - 0x75cac000     C:\windows\syswow64\MSCTF.dll
0x749c0000 - 0x749f8000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvinit.dll
0x74970000 - 0x749b6000     C:\PROGRA~2\Sophos\SOPHOS~1\SOPHOS~1.DLL
0x774a0000 - 0x774a5000     C:\windows\syswow64\PSAPI.DLL
0x67620000 - 0x676df000     D:\usr\java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x66be0000 - 0x66f6b000     D:\usr\java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x71e30000 - 0x71e37000     C:\windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x76360000 - 0x76395000     C:\windows\syswow64\WS2_32.dll
0x74be0000 - 0x74be6000     C:\windows\syswow64\NSI.dll
0x733a0000 - 0x733d2000     C:\windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x70a20000 - 0x70a2c000     D:\usr\java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x6edf0000 - 0x6ee11000     D:\usr\java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\bin\java.dll
0x700d0000 - 0x700e3000     D:\usr\java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x70300000 - 0x7030d000     D:\usr\java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\bin\prism-d3d.dll
0x655e0000 - 0x657a3000     C:\windows\system32\d3d9.dll
0x74a60000 - 0x74a69000     C:\windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x6f5b0000 - 0x6f5b6000     C:\windows\system32\d3d8thk.dll
0x6f4a0000 - 0x6f4b3000     C:\windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
0x71740000 - 0x717c0000     C:\windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x508f0000 - 0x51ac3000     C:\windows\system32\igdumdim32.dll
0x65270000 - 0x655db000     C:\windows\system32\igdusc32.dll
0x6eae0000 - 0x6eb07000     D:\usr\java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\bin\glass.dll
0x74d20000 - 0x74d9b000     C:\windows\syswow64\COMDLG32.dll
0x74dd0000 - 0x75a1b000     C:\windows\syswow64\SHELL32.dll
0x75fd0000 - 0x7612c000     C:\windows\syswow64\ole32.dll
0x75a70000 - 0x75aff000     C:\windows\syswow64\OLEAUT32.dll
0x685e0000 - 0x6865c000     D:\usr\java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\bin\libxml2.dll
0x6eab0000 - 0x6eada000     D:\usr\java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\bin\libxslt.dll
0x626a0000 - 0x63201000     D:\usr\java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\bin\jfxwebkit.dll
0x74730000 - 0x74746000     C:\windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x746f0000 - 0x7472b000     C:\windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x74bf0000 - 0x74c73000     C:\windows\syswow64\CLBCatQ.DLL
0x6dcb0000 - 0x6dde1000     C:\windows\system32\WindowsCodecs.dll
0x71ec0000 - 0x71f0c000     C:\windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x70490000 - 0x704c1000     C:\windows\system32\EhStorShell.dll
0x76490000 - 0x7662d000     C:\windows\syswow64\SETUPAPI.dll
0x76630000 - 0x76657000     C:\windows\syswow64\CFGMGR32.dll
0x75fb0000 - 0x75fc2000     C:\windows\syswow64\DEVOBJ.dll
0x6f090000 - 0x6f185000     C:\windows\system32\PROPSYS.dll
0x69050000 - 0x69459000     C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\Office14\GROOVEEX.DLL
0x74790000 - 0x74833000     C:\windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_50934f2ebcb7eb57\MSVCR90.dll
0x74840000 - 0x748ce000     C:\windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_50934f2ebcb7eb57\MSVCP90.dll
0x748d0000 - 0x748fb000     C:\windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.atl_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_51cd0a7abbe4e19b\ATL90.DLL
0x68a50000 - 0x68e6a000     C:\PROGRA~2\COMMON~1\MICROS~1\OFFICE14\Cultures\office.odf
0x676e0000 - 0x67f45000     C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\Office14\1033\GrooveIntlResource.dll
0x6eba0000 - 0x6ec10000     C:\windows\system32\ntshrui.dll
0x73d00000 - 0x73d19000     C:\windows\system32\srvcli.dll
0x71400000 - 0x7140b000     C:\windows\system32\cscapi.dll
0x70fe0000 - 0x70fea000     C:\windows\system32\slc.dll
0x6b100000 - 0x6b121000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Ink\rtscom.dll
0x698d0000 - 0x6990d000     D:\usr\java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\bin\javafx-font.dll
0x10000000 - 0x10038000     C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\SysWOW64\BtMmHook.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xbootclasspath:D:\usr\java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\resources.jar;D:\usr\java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\rt.jar;D:\usr\java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\jsse.jar;D:\usr\java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\jce.jar;D:\usr\java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\charsets.jar;D:\usr\java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\jfr.jar;D:\usr\java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\jfxrt.jar 
java_command: TestJFX
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=D:\usr\java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre
PATH=D:/usr/java/jre1.8.0_74_32bit/bin/client;D:/usr/java/jre1.8.0_74_32bit/bin;D:/usr/java/jre1.8.0_74_32bit/lib/i386;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lenovo\Access Connections\;D:\usr\java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin;C:\Users\Albert.Guirao\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\git_local\bin;D:\usr\tools\oracle\instantclient-basic;C:\Program Files\SourceGear\Common\DiffMerge\;C:\Program Files\Perforce;C:\Program Files\Perforce\DVCS\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\Users\Albert.Guirao\AppData\Roaming\npm;D:\usr\ide\eclipseDGR;
USERNAME=albert.guirao
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 4 (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 58 stepping 9, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, aes, erms, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, tscinv

Memory: 4k page, physical 8078996k(2816220k free), swap 16156156k(10014016k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.80-b11) for windows-x86 JRE (1.7.0_80-b15), built on Apr 10 2015 13:33:35 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1600

time: Fri Mar 04 11:32:43 2016
elapsed time: 12 seconds
```

The app crashes with jdk1.7.0_71. I've also tried with jre1.8.0_74 with same result.

I've been able to load the very same HTML with Google Chrome where I can click the button many times without any issue. Google Chrome crashes at first click if I rise the size of the string from 20MB to 40MB. With just 20MB it seems Chrome releases memory when necessary and it never crashes.

My goal is to avoid random crashes in a JavaFX app after calling some functions which return strings with sizes from 1KB to 32MB. It seems something is accumulating in the WebEngine and even with medium sized strings the app crashes after a number user interactions.

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23467797/javafx-nullpointerexception-when-rendering-big-image -Dprism.order=sw
-Xmx1024m

Comment: Results in: 
GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline failed for com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/sun/prism/sw/SWPipeline**
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195)
 at com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline(GraphicsPipeline.java:150)
...