# Error after deploying a javafx application

Tags: java, javafx

I have developed an application in `javafx`. It works very well on my laptop even when I deploy it and run on my computer, but when I install it on another pc the application starts normally, but does not display any interface (the task bar it is present). When I run the `.jar` with `java -jar monapp.jar` command I have an error in console
[error shown in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGw3o.png)
Please help.

Comment: Do you have the same version of JVM on both pc?

Comment: yes i do! i have used the version 8 of java and javafx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23467797/javafx-nullpointerexception-when-rendering-big-image 
try

Comment: no screenshots of text, instead, simply c&p